# Best way to see if a number is fractional or not

Tags: python

I'm looking to differentiate between a number like
`2.0` or `2` and an actual fractional number such as `2.4`. What would be the best way to do this? Currently I'm doing:

```
def is_fractional(num):
    if not str(num).replace('.','').isdigit(): return
    return float(num) != int(num)

>>> is_fractional(2)
False
>>> is_fractional(2.1)
True
>>> is_fractional(2.0)
False
>>> is_fractional('a')
>>>
```

Comment: Maybe `abs(x - int(x)) > 0`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That operation is built-in:

```
>>> 5.0.is_integer()
True
>>> 5.00000001.is_integer()
False
>>> 4.9999999.is_integer()
False
```

Documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-float).

**ADDENDUM**

The initial solution only works for `float`. Here's a more complete answer, with tests:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def is_integer(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return True
    elif isinstance(x, float):
        return x.is_integer()
    elif isinstance(x, Decimal):
        return x.as_integer_ratio()[1] == 1
    return False

good = [
    0, 
    0.0, 
    3, 
    -9999999999999999999999, 
    -2.0000000000000,
    Decimal("3.000000"),
    Decimal("-9")
]
bad = [
    -9.99999999999999,
    "dogs",
    Decimal("-4.00000000000000000000000000000000001"),
    Decimal("0.99999999999999999999999999999999999")
]

for x in good:
    assert is_integer(x)
for x in bad:
    assert not is_integer(x)
print("All tests passed")
```

Comment: The issue with this approach, is I'm often dealing with decimals so I'd need to first cast it. Otherwise, I get: `AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'is_integer'`

Comment: Good point. `is_integer` only exists on `float`s. For `Decimal` I would go with `d.as_integer_ratio()[1] == 1`.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Ah, the `as_integer_ratio` is better than `as_tuple` and counting trailing zeros. +1

Comment: I think so... I tried a few of  the `decimal.Decimal` methods and found this one to be particularly nice and to work for everything I threw at it. Unbounded integers in Python are so nice.

Comment: @RayToal additionally, why does something like `>>> float(-9999999999999999999999)==int(-9999999999999999999999)
>>> False` happen?

Comment: Floats do not have arbitrary precision! They are stored in 64 bits with only 53 bits of mantissa, which is 15-17 significant figures. If you evaluate `float(-9999999999999999999999)` in Python, you get `-1e+22`. The value -9999999999999999999999 is simply not representable in 64-bit IEEE 754. The closest representable value to that is -10000000000000000000000. But in the `int` type, all integers are representable.

Answer (score 3):

Why do not check if the difference between the truncation to integer and the exact value is not zero?

```
is_frac = lambda x: int(x)-x != 0
```

Answer (score 3):

If some of your numbers are `decimal.Decimal`s, they might have range issues where conversion to float fails, or drops the fractional part that actually exists, depending on their precision:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> x = decimal.Decimal('1.00000000000000000000000000000000000001')
>>> str(x)
'1.00000000000000000000000000000000000001'
>>> float(x).is_integer()
True

>>> y = decimal.Decimal('1e5000')
>>> str(y)
'1E+5000'
>>> float(y)
inf
```

The `str` method will generally work (modulo problem cases like the one illustrated above), so you could stick with that, but it might be better to attempt to use `is_integer` and use a fallback if that fails:

```
try:
   return x.is_integer()
except AttributeError:
   pass
```

(as others note, you'll need to check for `int` and `long` here as well, if those are allowed types, since they are integers by definition but lack an `is_integer` attribute).

At this point, it's worth considering all of the other answers, but here's a specific decimal.Decimal handler:

```
# optional: special case decimal.Decimal here
try:
    as_tuple = x.as_tuple()
    trailing0s = len(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda i: i == 0, reversed(as_tuple[1]))))
    return as_tuple[2] + trailing0s < 0
except (AttributeError, IndexError): # no as_tuple, or not 3 elements long, etc
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Python includes a `fractions` module that generates fractions (rational numbers) from strings, `float`s, integers, and much more. Just create a `Fraction` and check whether its denominator is other than 1 (the `Fraction` constructor will automatically reduce the number to lowest terms):

```
from fractions import Fraction

def is_fractional(num):
    return Fraction(num).denominator != 1
```

Note that the method above may raise an exception if the conversion to a Fraction fails. In this case, it's not known whether the object is fractional.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with `decimal` module or with a `float` object, you can do this easily:

```
def is_factional(num):
    return isinstance(num, (float, Decimal))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it (assuming e.g. 2/2 is not "fractional" in the sense you have in mind):

```
# could also extend to other numeric types numpy.float32 
from decimal import Decimal

def is_frac(n):
  numeric_types = (int, float, Decimal)
  assert isinstance(n, numeric_types), 'n must be numeric :/'
  # (ints are never fractions)
  if type(n) is int: return False
  return n != float(int(n))

# various sorts of numbers 
ns = [-1, -1.0, 0, 0.1, 1, 1.0, 1., 2.3, 1e0, 1e3, 1.1e3, 
      Decimal(3), Decimal(3.0), Decimal(3.1)]

# confirm that values are as expected 
dict(zip(ns, [is_frac(n) for n in ns]))
```

This will only work if `n` is an `int` or a `float` or `decimal.Decimal`. But you could extend it to handle other numeric types such as `numpy.float64` or `numpy.int32` by just including them in `numeric_types`.