# why is a float value triggering my first if statement?

Tags: python-3.x, math

Using the variable 4 as an example, the result of 2.0 is clearly a float. I have no idea why it triggers my first if statement. Is it because square_root is a reference to the variable and not actually 2.0? I am expecting to take complex numbers and I need "is not isinstance" to work properly.

```
square_root = 4 ** (1/2)


if square_root != isinstance(square_root,float):
    return False
if square_root.is_integer():
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: What **type** does `isinstance` return? It is, pretty sure, not the **type** of `square_root ` so they won't be `==`

Comment: What is `squared`? Please post a [mcve], one that doesn't depend on variables defined elsewhere (although, in this case, @DeepSpace has clearly identified the problem)

Comment: I fixed my post, I meant square_root instead of squared

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to see if a number is fractional or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53017876/best-way-to-see-if-a-number-is-fractional-or-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isinstance` already returns the boolean you are looking for, comparing it against `square_root` makes no sense at all and it will always be `False` because it compares a numerical value to a boolean.

Technically, `if square_root != isinstance(square_root,float):` should just be `if isinstance(square_root,float):`, but I'm not sure when exactly you expect this check to be `False`. `4 ** (1/2)` (using **any** numbers) will **always** return a `float`.

Comment: I will replacing 4 with a variable. I am expecting to receive variables that are not floats such as complex numbers. How can I use "is not isinstance"?

Comment: @DanNand `if not ...`

Comment: ah so close, I was stuck on using !. Thank you!

Comment: Quibble: `1.0 == True` evaluates to `True` so "it will always be False because it compares a numerical value to a boolean" isn't quite accurate. Beyond that, good answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman Indeed, and so does `0.0 == False`. I deliberately ignored these 2 (4?) edge cases.